# Decoder D3D9 example and running in CUDA

Tags: cuda, decode, h.264

I am new to CUDA decoder and trying to figure out how the code for CUDA decoder D3D9 sample works. I downloaded the sample code and try to run the code with the sample video with `g_bUseDisplay = true` but i am getting  a stack call error at the running of this command

```
g_pD3DDevice->SetViewport(&oViewport);
```

Can anyone help me out here please ? I try to google it but cannot find much and stuck at this point. I want to change the code to run a H.264 codec and save the output file or display it but cannot run the sample code. Also if someone can help me in saving the output frame. Thank you.

Comment: Can you run the sample code if you don't make any changes to it?

Comment: nope i am still unable to run it without any changes but if i make g_bUseDisplay = false then it runs okay but without any video output

Comment: The sample code by default has `g_bUseDisplay = false`, so I guess that means you *can* run the sample code if you don't make any changes to it.  What are your machine details (GPU, driver, OS)?  Which CUDA version?  Have you installed the directx sdk?

Comment: On a windows 7 x64 laptop with Quadro1000M, with CUDA 5, June 2010 DX SDK, and Visual Studio 2008 (building a win32 "Debug" project) I loaded the cudaDecodeD3D9 sample project, I then changed `g_bUseDisplay` to `true` and also `g_bUseInterop` to `true`, and I was able to successfully compile and run the sample, and see the decoded video in the window that opened up.

Comment: Thank you i figured it out. I was having problems with flags. Thank you very much.. If you can put your last comment as a answer so i can accept that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [SDK sample](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-samples/index.html#cuda-video-decoder-d3d9-api) comes with default flags that are set up to decode but not display the decoded frames.

As indicated [here](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-samples/index.html#cuda-video-decoder-d3d9-api) it should be possible to just pass the `-displayvideo` command line parameter to the application, and you should be able to see the decoded frames.  Alternatively, I was able to set the two flags `g_bUseInterop` and `g_bUseDisplay` to `true` and also see the decoded video while passing no additional command line parameters.